# C# Datatable - group by multiple columns with linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a Datatable like this

```
| Supplier  | Product | Price1 | Price2 | Price3 | ... | PriceN |
|-----------|---------|--------|--------|--------|-----|--------|
| Supplier1 | Orange  | 100    | 105    | 150    | ... | 180    |
| Supplier1 | Orange  | 110    | 130    | 140    | ... | 180    |
| Supplier2 | Orange  | 200    | 250    | 270    | ... | 350    |
| Supplier2 | Orange  | 250    | 270    | 320    | ... | 270    |
```

I want to group rows as next:

```
| Supplier  | Product | Price1  | Price2  | Price3  | ... | PriceN  |
|-----------|---------|---------|---------|---------|-----|---------|
| Supplier1 | Orange  | 100-110 | 105-130 | 140-150 | ... | 180     |
| Supplier2 | Orange  | 200-250 | 250-270 | 270-320 | ... | 270-350 |
```

Count of columns like "PriceN" can be arbitrary.
How can I do this with LINQ?

Comment: Sorry, my question was not full. In this table also can be other columns names and count of which is also unknown. But grouping must be only by Price columns

Comment: @Dimity Could we solve your problem with one of our answers?

Comment: All suggested approaches are same. The main problem is that I do not know count of columns that must be collapsed and count and names of colums for GroupBy. I know only that column names for collapsing start from "Price"

Comment: How do you store those data? Is a class / object in way, i.e. the datatable contains objects of type "Supplier"? How are the prices stored, e.g. in a list / array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by `Supplier` and `Product` as

```
var result = from x in data
             group x by new { x.Supplier, x.Product }
             select x;
```

or

```
var result = data.GroupBy(x => new { x.Supplier, x.Product });
```

similarly you can use any number of property in group clause

Answer (score 0):

you have to group by it separately in another lambda expression

```
result.tolist().GroupBy(p=> p.x,p.x2,p.x3 ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GroupBy` and `JOIN` to concatenate the values of the price columns:

```
var groupedSupplier = supplier.GroupBy(s => new { s.Supplier, s.Product })
                              .Select(supplier => supplier.Supplier, 
                                                  supplier.Product,
                                                  supplier.Price1 = string.Join(",", supplier.Select(x => x.Price1)),
                                                  supplier.Price2 = string.Join(",", supplier.Select(x => x.Price2)),
...);
```

Comment: This approach works if you know count and names of columns for GroupBy and count and names of column which must be selected. Sorry my question was not full, I commented it with this remark

Answer (score 0):

To group by multiple columns in lambda expression use:

```
var groupedSupplier = supplier.GroupBy(s => s.Supplier,
                                       s => s.Product)
```

For details, please see chapter 11 of "C# in Depth" by Jon Skeet, Chapter 11 "Query expressions and LINQ to Objects: 11.6 Groupings and continuations", http://csharpindepth.com/